# Creating content with content type: only Title is displaying on first click not the other fields

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I have a content type to submit events/workshops etc for a conference.

The fields I have are like this:

Label; Machine name; Field type; Widget; Event Title; title; Node module element;

Fields:
Panel Image; field_panel_image; Image; Image;

Room; field_room; Entity Reference; Drag & Drop;

Timeslot; field_timeslot; Entity Reference; Drag & Drop;

Speaker First and Middle Name; field_speaker_first_and_middle_n; Text; Text field;

Speaker Last Name; field_speaker_last_name; Text; Text field;

Speaker Email(s); field_speaker1_email; Text; Text field;

Speaker Affiliation(s); field_speaker1_affiliation; Text; Text field;

Speaker Biography; field_speaker1_biography; Text; Text field;

Problem is that when the authorized user clicks on the link which leads to 
the add content type form it does just display the "Event Title" field.
When I am logged in as admin I see the whole form.

But the "normal" authorized user needs first to hit save after typing in the event title and then the site displays the title of that just created node and an edit button. When the authorized user clicks on "edit" s/he sees the whole form.

Is there a way where the authorized user sees the whole form immediately when
s/he calls up that content type form?

(Some of the fields mentioned above (room and time slot) have the permissions set so that just admins should be able to see it. But the other permissions are set for authorized users as well.

Thank you.

Marcus

**../admin/reports/status:**
Drupal 7.58
Web server Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

CKEditor 4.5.4
Code per Node CodeMirror v5.36.1 is installed.
CodeMirror is installed and it is a compatible version. Excellent!
Configuration file Protected
CSS Injector directory writable
CSS Injector Directory public://css_injector is writable

CTools CSS Cache
Database system version
Database updates
Date iCal iCalcreator library is installed, version: 2.20.2 found
Drupal core update status
File system Writable (public download method)
GD library PNG support 2.1.1-dev
GD library rotate and desaturate effects  2.1.1-dev

jQuery Update jQuery 1.7.2 (configure) and jQuery UI 1.10.2
Warning
Module and theme update status
There are updates available for one or more of your modules or themes. To ensure the proper functioning of your site, you should update as soon as possible. See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.

Node Access Permissions  540 permissions in use
If the site is experiencing problems with permissions to content, you may have to rebuild the permissions cache. Rebuilding will remove all privileges to content and replace them with permissions based on the current modules and settings. Rebuilding may take some time if there is a lot of content or complex permission settings. After rebuilding has completed, content will automatically use the new permissions. Rebuild permissions

OpenSSL Enabled (OpenSSL 1.0.1t 3 May 2016)
PHP    5.6.33-0+deb8u1 (more information)
PHP extensions  Enabled

PHP memory limit  256M
PHP register globals  Disabled

Plupload library 1.5.8
SOAP Enabled

Unicode library PHP Mbstring Extension
Update notifications Enabled

Upload progress Not enabled
Your server is capable of displaying file upload progress through APC, but it is not enabled. Add apc.rfc1867 = 1 to your php.ini configuration. Alternatively, it is recommended to use PECL uploadprogress, which supports more than one simultaneous upload.

Views Data Export temporary directory Exists

---

**MODULES ENABLED**
Name
Administration menu Adminimal Theme (adminimal_admin_menu)

Auto Assign Role (autoassignrole)

Automatic Entity Labels(auto_entitylabel)

Backup and Migrate(backup_migrate)

Better Exposed Filters(better_exposed_filters)

Block Class (block_class)

Bootstrap Login Modal(bootstrap_login_modal)

Calendar (calendar)

CKEditor Link (ckeditor_link)

CKEditor (ckeditor)

COD Email (cod_email)

COD Session (cod_session)

Code per Node (cpn)

Coffee (coffee)

Commerce Billy Mail(commerce_billy_mail)

Commerce Coupon(commerce_coupon)

Commerce Event Ticket(commerce_event_ticket)

Commerce Features(commerce_features)

Commerce iATS (commerce_iats)

Composer Autoloader(composer_autoloader)

Conditional Fields(conditional_fields)

Contact (contact)

Content Access (content_access)

Content Type Clone(content_type_clone)

Contextual links (contextual)

CSS Injector (css_injector)

Database logging (dblog)

Date All Day (date_all_day)

Date iCal (date_ical)

Date Tools (date_tools)

Devel generate (devel_generate)

Devel (devel)

Display Suite Extras (ds_extras)

Display Suite Format (ds_format)

Display Suite Forms (ds_forms)

Display Suite UI (ds_ui)

Distribution Update Status Manager (distro_update)

Draggableviews (draggableviews)

Empty Front Page(empty_front_page)

Enabled modules (enabled_modules)

Entity Reference Autocreate(entityreference_autocreate)

Entity reference autofill addressfield(entityreference_autofill_addressfield)

Entity reference autofill OG(entityreference_autofill_og)

Entity Reference Drag & Drop(entityreference_dragdrop)

Exclude node title(exclude_node_title)

Features Diff (features_diff)

Field group multiple(field_group_multiple)

Field reference (field_reference)

Field tools taxonomy(field_tools_taxonomy)

Field tools (field_tools)

Fieldable Panels Panes(fieldable_panels_panes)

FileField Sources Plupload(filefield_sources_plupload)

Google Analytics (googleanalytics)

Hidden CAPTCHA (hidden_captcha)

Image CAPTCHA (image_captcha)

Image URL Formatter(image_url_formatter)

IMCE plupload (imce_plupload)

jQuery Countdown Timer(jquery_countdown_timer)

Media WYSIWYG (media_wysiwyg)

Media: oEmbed (media_oembed)

Menu Block (menu_block)

Mime Mail (mimemail)

Module filter (module_filter)

Multifield table (multifield_table)

Organic groups access control(og_access)

Organic groups field access(og_field_access)

Organic groups register(og_register)

Panels In-Place Editor (panels_ipe)

Payment UI (commerce_payment_ui)

PHP filter (php)

Rules Scheduler (rules_scheduler)

Session Room - Schedule validation (validate_session_booking)

Statistics (statistics)

Stylizer (stylizer)

ThemeKey UI (themekey_ui)

Comment: Please specify Drupal version; names and versions of the relevant modules that are in use. Also, if you’re using any node or field access modules make sure to rebuild the permissions, you can check that at the status page under reports.

Comment: thanks for this. I edited the text and added the info on enabled modules, drupal version etc

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the permissions?

Comment: I can think of 3 possible solutions based on the installed modules and how you describe the issue. I believe one of them will help you solve it.

Comment: Yes. I did that to. This and disconnecting from organic groups did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you rebuilt the permissions first.

If the issue still exists, first check the permissions at `/admin/people/permissions` page. If the desired roles don't have required permissions for those fields.

For what you ask, create/edit/delete permissions must be given to desired roles.

Also check "Organic Group" settings. Field permissions might be misconfigured. This is more likely the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tips osman. Disconnecting form organic group one of the fields within the content type did the trick.....

Answer (score 0):

*If the previous two answers don't apply;*

Third possible solution might be related with Conditional Fields.

Make sure to check all fields for their settings. Check if any of them has conditions defined making them available only on edit page, but not on create page as well.